# Is matrix B obtained from matrix A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization

Assuming a matrix $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{4096 \times 4096}$ sampled from a standard normal distribution $N(0, 1)$, and another matrix $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{4096 \times 4096}$ either sampled from a standard normal distribution or obtained by permuting matrix $\mathbf{A}$ in the form $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{P}(\mathbf{A} + \varepsilon)\mathbf{P}^T$, where $\mathbf{P}$ is a permutation matrix, and $\varepsilon \in \mathbb{R}^{4096 \times 4096}$ is a noise matrix sampled from $0.1N(0, 1)$.

**Question 1:** How can I identify whether $ \mathbf{B} $ is obtained by permuting $ \mathbf{A} $?

**Question 2:** Is there an efficient algorithm to obtain matrix  $ \mathbf{P}  $ if  $ \mathbf{B}  $ is in the form  $ \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{P} (\mathbf{A} + \varepsilon) \mathbf{P}^T  $? If too complex, would removing  $ \varepsilon  $ simplify the problem?

**Efforts Made:**
I have conducted an analysis based on the fact that matrices  $ \mathbf{A}  $ and  $\mathbf{P}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{P}^T $ must share identical eigenvalues. Using Python, I computed the eigenvalues of matrices  $ \mathbf{A}  $ and  $ \mathbf{B}  $. Sorting eigenvalues became necessary due to disorder in the order of eigenvalues from the permuted matrix calculated by Python. The presence of noise  $ \varepsilon  $ and the possibility that matrices  $ \mathbf{A}  $ and  $ \mathbf{B}  $ are sampled from identical distributions (with closely sorted eigenvalues) has made it challenging to determine if  $ \mathbf{B}  $ is indeed obtained by permuting  $ \mathbf{A}  $.

Comment: In principle, this problem is amenable to integer linear programming formulation, where $P$ is formed by binary variables, and one wants to minimize variable $b$ under the constraints $-b \leq D_{ij} \leq b$ for the elements of $D:=BP - PA$ and all row/column sums of $P$ equal 1. However, I'm not sure how solving ILP for size $4096\times 4096$ will work in practice.

Comment: Thank you very much! I attempted to use ILP to solve this problem in Python, but unfortunately, I couldn't obtain any results. This may be attributed to the high complexity, especially given the size of $4096\times 4096$.

Answer (score 3):

We can match rows of $A$ and $B$ by sorting them and looking at the difference. Specifically, the mismatch between the sorted row $A'_i$ and sorted row $B'_j$ can be estimated by $\|A'_i-B'_j\|_2^2$. We can then optimally match A and B by standard solvers for [the assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem). This recovers the permutation if $B$ is a permutation of $A$.

We can also find the permutation by matching the columns similarly. This lets us distinguish between permuted $B$ and independently sampled $B$: just check if the estimated permutations for rows and columns are the same.

**Edit:** As pointed out in a comment, this method fails when the noise intensity is doubled. We can make the algorithm robust to more noise by iterating the matching step with the previous estimate for the permutation (instead of sorting, we use the previously estimated permutation).

This seems to work for $\epsilon \sim 0.5 \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ (but breaks down for 0.6). Any algorithm will eventually fail when the noise increases, so I'll stop here. I tested with 4 iterations, which took roughly 2 minutes per instance on my laptop.

If the algorithm was to be used on more realistic data, I would expect some more robust mismatch estimators to perform better. In particular, I would try replacing the 2-norm with the more robust 1-norm. Also, depending on the data, I would try to standardize it (e.g. subtracting the mean from each row). Finally, the test `if (p1 == p2).all():` would be replaced with a check tolerant to an imperfect match.

Code with iteration for improved robustness to noise:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

def findPerm(A, B, num_iterations = 4):
  Aperm = np.argsort(A)
  Bperm = np.argsort(B)

  for it in range(num_iterations):
    Apermed = np.take_along_axis(A, Aperm, -1)
    Bpermed = np.take_along_axis(B, Bperm, -1)

    # diff[i,j] = np.linalg.norm(A[i]-B[j])**2
    # But the equivalent implementation below is faster
    diff = np.sum(Apermed**2,axis=1).reshape(-1,1) + np.sum(Bpermed**2,axis=1).reshape(1,-1) - 2 * Apermed@Bpermed.T

    # Min cost matching of A and B
    row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(diff)
    assert(row_ind == np.arange(n)).all() # col_ind contains the result

    Aperm = row_ind.reshape(1,-1)
    Bperm = col_ind.reshape(1,-1)

  return np.argsort(col_ind) # Invert permutation

def solve(A, B):
  p1 = findPerm(A,B)
  p2 = findPerm(A.T,B.T)
  if (p1 == p2).all():
    return p1 # B matches A, return permutation
  else:
    return None # B is independent of A

n = 4096

for _ in range(10): # Check 10 random instances
  A = np.random.normal(size=(n,n))
  p = np.random.permutation(n)
  eps = 0.5*np.random.normal(size=(n,n))
  B = (A+eps)[p,:][:,p]
  C = np.random.normal(size=(n,n))

  result = solve(A,B)
  assert (result == p).all()
  result = solve(A,C)
  assert (result == None)
  print('OK')
```

Original code:
I implemented the approach naively below. It takes about 15 seconds per instance on my laptop, and seems to work consistently.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

def findPerm(A, B):
  A = np.sort(A)
  B = np.sort(B)
  # diff[i,j] = np.linalg.norm(A[i]-B[j])**2
  # But the equivalent implementation below is faster
  diff = np.sum(A**2,axis=1).reshape(-1,1) + np.sum(B**2,axis=1).reshape(1,-1) - 2 * A@B.T

  # Min cost matching of A and B
  row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(diff)
  assert(row_ind == np.arange(n)).all() # col_ind contains the result

  return np.argsort(col_ind) # Invert permutation

def solve(A, B):
  p1 = findPerm(A,B)
  p2 = findPerm(A.T,B.T)
  if (p1 == p2).all():
    return p1 # B matches A, return permutation
  else:
    return None # B is independent of A

n = 4096

for _ in range(10): # Check 10 random instances
  A = np.random.normal(size=(n,n))
  p = np.random.permutation(n)
  eps = 0.1*np.random.normal(size=(n,n))
  B = (A+eps)[p,:][:,p]
  C = np.random.normal(size=(n,n))

  result = solve(A,B)
  assert (result == p).all()
  result = solve(A,C)
  assert (result == None)
  print('OK')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful response. I have executed the code, and it worked well with a noise intensity of 0.1. However, when I increased it to 0.2, the algorithm failed to perform. I suspect that the sorting process is diminishing the algorithm's robustness. I wonder if there is a method that is more resilient to noise (perhaps I am being too greedy). Thanks again for your assistance!